# Laravel problem with relation leading zero

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eager-loading, leading-zero

I have come across problems with Laravel relations when couple of model ids are identical but another has leading zero and the another has not.

```
Product ID | Productname  
-----------|------------ 
012345     | Product A
12345      | Product B
```

If those relations are loaded in the same query, only the first one will be returned and the other will not.

The database columns are strings and in the Product model I have been set the incrementing to false and cast of id attribute to string. Doesn't Laravel's eager loading take leading zeros into account?

I'm not able to change those product ids with leading zeros.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the code for relationship definition.

Comment: Could you show us your Model Classes, please.

Comment: The eloquent model have a property to set primary key type. Change it from integer to string. Also it have a key to define if the primary key is auto increment or not. Set it to false. Not sure the name of this properties, but I'm sure u can find it! :-)

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, but downvote was following up, you need to define `public $incrementing = false;`and inside the migration set the type of the attribute to `string`.

Comment: "I have been set the incrementing to false"

Answer (score 0):

I just run a test on a local laravel installation and I can't reproduce the problem.

Are you sure it is not a problem of the way you structure a query? Because if at any time during your program the `$id` variable is treated as an integer, the future conversion to string will remove the leading zero.

For example, maybe you get the id from the request:

```
$productId = $request->get('product_id');
```

At this point `$productId` is considered an integer, so if you use `productId` to  query your DB, the leading zero will be removed.

You need to be sure that during the lifecycle of your request that variable is never converted to integer.

You can test the proper query using [tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#tinker), and obtaining your products manually:

```
Product::find('012345');
Product::find('12345');
```

Comment: I'm querying another model that has product as relation. I think this problem is related to eager loading so that the framework thinks that the product has been already loaded even if there's a leading zero in another. Those are working correctly with separated queries.